# Is type casting address vars to contract types more expensive than defining vars as contract types? And why?

Tags: solidity, gas, optimization

Let's say we have two options for defining a token as a storage variable:

**A**:

```
address token = 0xc0ffee...;
...
for(...) {
  IERC20(token).transfer(...);
}
```

**B**:

```
IERC20 token = IERC20(0xc0ffee...);
...
for(...) {
  token.transfer(...);
}
```

From both options above, what would be the more gas-efficient option for accessing and interacting with the token contract? And why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no difference in gas costs, at least not when the optimizer is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From both options above, what would be the more gas-efficient option
> for accessing and interacting with the token contract? And why?

They are exactly the same.

There is no difference between `address` and any interface or contract for that matter. The true underlying type is always address. `IERC20` or anything else is just a way to interpret an `address` as being the identifier of a specific type of contract.

See the following example :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface iToken {
        function transfer() external view; 
}

contract Token is iToken {
        function transfer() public override view {
                return;
        }
}

contract Test1 {

        address token;

        constructor(address _token) {
                token = _token;
        }

        function test() public view {
                iToken(token).transfer();             
        }
}

contract Test2 {

        iToken token;

        constructor(iToken _token) {
                token = _token;
        }

        function test() public view {
                token.transfer();
        }
}

contract Test3 {

        Token token;

        constructor(Token _token) {
                token = _token;
        }

        function test() public view {
                token.transfer();
        }
}
```

Calling the `test` function on Test1, Test2 or Test3 cost `26277` gas in all cases (Remix - default settings).

You could also check storage slot 0 of all TestX contract's and see that they all have the very same value : the `address` of the Token contract. There is no difference at the lower levels.